# Artifactory X-ray Database sync got stuck at "calculating"

Tags: postgresql, artifactory, jfrog-xray

My artifactory, x-ray, and database services are up and running
while i am doing online database sync it got stuck at 99% and not moving forward.

And I have restarted the database sync again. Still database sync is stuck at calculating state.

please see the attached screenshot

[image]

getting below error in the logs

> 2022-01-24T14:14:21.715Z [33m[jfxan][0m [1m[31m[ERROR][0m [90b51099218cab1d] [grpc_utils:32                 ] [main                ] (--wrapper--)Refreshing [permissions cache invalidation Internal] gRPC stream - got an error (status code: %!s(MISSING)) - resubscribe expected
> 2022-01-24T14:39:21.742Z [33m[jfxan][0m [1m[31m[ERROR][0m [90b51099218cab1d] [grpc_utils:32                 ] [main                ] (--wrapper--)Refreshing [permissions cache invalidation Internal] gRPC stream - got an error (status code: %!s(MISSING)) - resubscribe expected
> 2022-01-24T14:49:21.762Z [33m[jfxan][0m [1m[31m[ERROR][0m [90b51099218cab1d] [grpc_utils:32                 ] [main                ] (--wrapper--)Refreshing [permissions cache invalidation Internal] gRPC stream - got an error (status code: %!s(MISSING)) - resubscribe expected
> 2022-01-24T14:54:21.782Z [33m[jfxan][0m [1m[31m[ERROR][0m [90b51099218cab1d] [grpc_utils:32                 ] [main                ] (--wrapper--)Refreshing [permissions cache invalidation Internal] gRPC stream - got an error (status code: %!s(MISSING)) - resubscribe expected
> 2022-01-24T15:04:21.806Z [33m[jfxan][0m [1m[31m[ERROR][0m [90b51099218cab1d] [grpc_utils:32                 ] [main                ] (--wrapper--)Refreshing [permissions cache invalidation Internal] gRPC stream - got an error (status code: %!s(MISSING)) - resubscribe expected

Comment: what error do you see in the xray-server-service.log for DB sync?

Comment: Also, refer to this KB article https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-overcome-issue-when-xray-online-db-sync-fails-with-401/ if you got 401 errors in the Xray logs

Comment: These are the logs i am seeing in  xray-server-service.log  2022-01-25T15:04:45.089Z [jfxr ] [INFO ] [a06c53e615fcc776] [unified_config_service:312    ] [main                ] Synced projects resources successfully
2022-01-25T15:07:14.867Z [jfxr ] [INFO ] [                ] [samplers:327                  ] [main                ] Total disk space: 75.0GB, available disk space: 11.5GB

Comment: check for errors or warnings?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are meeting the system requirements for Xray installation as listed here:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/System+Requirements

For Global Database Online Synchronizing, If you are using a firewall, to allow the database sync to complete successfully, you need to add the following URLs to your firewall's whitelist:

```
https://releases.jfrog.io/
https://releases-cdn.jfrog.io
https://dl.bintray.com/
https://akamai.bintray.com
https://jxray.jfrog.io
```

To test the ability to sync, run the following REST API endpoint:

https://jxray.jfrog.io/api/v1/system/ping